# Xcode 6 and Constraints - Greyed out equal widths option

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, button, constraints

I am trying to use the constraints on xcode 6 with side-by-side objects but when I use the "add missing constraints" option, all of the elements resize properly except the side-by-side buttons where they stay the same size but one gets pushed out of the view.

[Image of View](http://i.cloudsync.it/kvsZhHL.png)

And I think I need to use the "Equal heights" constraint but it is greyed out :(

[Greyed out constraint Image](http://i.cloudsync.it/ICFzPpM.png)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to right-click drag from one of the objects to the other one to enable that option (It needs to know what heights should be equal)

Answer (score 1):

You can also:

1. In the Xcode document outline use Shift or Command and click on the items you want to add the equal size constraint to.
2. Then click the Pin button.
3. You can now click the checkbox to add 'equal width' or 'equal height' constraints.